# multipart email PHP variables

Tags: php, email, html-email, multipart

I'm sending a PHP multipart email, but for some reason the PHP variables aren't showing up inside the incoming mail (which I do receive in the nice HTML template). Below is the code, I'm sure that on the page the Session Variables are available because I display them on this very same page. Hope you guys can help!

```
$mail_ontv2 = " ".$_SESSION['emailcontact']." "; 

$_POST['onderwerp2'] = "Aanmelding";

    // set datum 
    $datum2 = date("d.m.Y H:i"); 

    //boundary
    $boundary = uniqid('np');


    $headers2 .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers2 .= "From: *** < info@***.nl >";
    $headers2 .= "To: ".$mail_ontv2."\r\n";
    $headers2 .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "";

    // set ip 
    $ip2 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

    //here is the content body
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "This is a MIME encoded message.";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

    //Plain text body
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "U heeft zich zojuist succesvol aangemeld bij ***.\n\n\n";     
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Uw gegevens:\n\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Bedrijfsnaam: " . $_SESSION['bedrijfsnaam'] . "\n"; 
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Adres: " . $_SESSION['straat'] . " " . $_SESSION['huisnummer'] . " \n"; 
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Postcode: " . $_SESSION['postcode'] . "\n"; 
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Plaats: " . $_SESSION['plaats'] . "\n\n"; 
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Telefoonnummer: " . $_SESSION['telefoonnummer'] . "\n"; 
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "E-mail adres: " . $_SESSION['email'] . "\n"; 
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "KvK-nummer: " . $_SESSION['kvk'] . "\n"; 
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "BTW-nummer: " . $_SESSION['btw'] . "\n"; 
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Rechtsvorm: " . $_SESSION['rechtsvorm'] . "\n\n"; 
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Contactpersoon: " . $_SESSION['contactpersoon'] . "\n"; 
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Geslacht: " . $_SESSION['geslachtcontactpersoon'] . "\n"; 
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Tel. nr. contactpersoon: " . $_SESSION['telefoonnummercontact'] . "\n"; 
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "E-mail adres contactpersoon: " . $_SESSION['emailcontact'] . "\n\n"; 
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Bent u een accounting bedrijf? " . $_SESSION['accounting'] . "\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Door u gekozen abonnement: " . $_SESSION['abonnement'] . "\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Gewenste gebruikersnaam: " . $_SESSION['gebruikersnaam'] . "\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Boekhoudprogramma: " . $_SESSION['boekhoudprogramma'] . "\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Twinfield abonnement? " . $_SESSION['twinfield'] . "\n\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Betalingsmethode: " . $_SESSION['betalingsmethode'] . "\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "E-mailadres factuur: " . $_SESSION['emailfactuur'] . "\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Bank: " . $_SESSION['bank'] . "\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Tenaamstelling: " . $_SESSION['tenaamstelling'] . "\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Rekeningnummer: " . $_SESSION['rekeningnummer'] . "\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Toestemming tot afschrijving: " . $_SESSION['afschrijving'] . "\n\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Akkoord met de voorwaarden? " . $_SESSION['voorwaarden'] . "\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Bent u gemachtigd? " . $_SESSION['gemachtigd'] . "\n\n";



    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Verstuurd op " . $datum . " via het ip " . $ip . "\n\n\n"; 
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Onze Algemene Voorwaarden: https://www.***.nl/wp-content/uploads/general/TC/***-AV-v1-1-NL.pdf \n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Onze Service level agreement: https://www.***.nl/wp-content/uploads/general/TC/***-SLA-v1-2-NL.pdf \n\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Dat u deze mail ontvangt betekend dat u akkoord ging \n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "met het bovenstaande. Opzegging is kosteloos mogelijk binnen 30 dagen. \n\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Met vriendelijke groet, \n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "*** N.V. \n";
        $inhoud_mail2 .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

    //Html body
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "

<html>
<body leftmargin=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" topmargin=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" offset=\"0\">

<table width=\"100%\" bgcolor=\"#e7e7e7\" cellpadding=\"10\" cellspacing=\"0\" background=\"http://www.***.nl/email/bc.jpg\">
    <tr valign=\"top\" align=\"center\">
        <td>
            <table width=\"550\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src=\"http://www.***.nl/email/email-header.png\" alt=\"Header **** Email\" /><br /><br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style=\"margin: 25px; padding:15px\" bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">

                        <h2 style=\"color:#545454; font-weight:600; font-size: 20px; letter-spacing:-1px; font-family:Verdana, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;\">Aanmelding ***!</h2>
                                                <p style=\"color:#3d3d3d;font-family:Verdana, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; line-height: 20px; font-size: 14px;\">




U heeft zich zojuist succesvol aangemeld bij ***.<br /><br /><Br />     
<b>Uw gegevens:</b><br /><Br />
Bedrijfsnaam: <?php echo $_SESSION[bedrijfsnaam]; ?>  <Br /> 
Adres: <?php echo $_SESSION[straat]; ?>  <?php echo $_SESSION[huisnummer]; ?> <Br /> 
Postcode: <?php echo $_SESSION[postcode]; ?>  <Br />
Plaats: <?php echo $_SESSION[plaats]; ?>  <Br /> 
Telefoonnummer: <?php echo $_SESSION[telefoonnummer]; ?>  <Br />
E-mail adres: <?php echo $_SESSION[email]; ?>  <Br />
KvK-nummer: <?php echo $_SESSION[kvk]; ?>  <Br />
BTW-nummer: <?php echo $_SESSION[btw]; ?>  <Br />
Rechtsvorm: <?php echo $_SESSION[rechtsvorm]; ?>  <Br /><Br />
Contactpersoon: <?php echo $_SESSION[contactpersoon]; ?>  <Br />
Geslacht: <?php echo $_SESSION[geslachtcontactpersoon]; ?>  <Br />
Tel. nr. contactpersoon: <?php echo $_SESSION[telefoonnummercontact]; ?>  <Br />
E-mail adres contactpersoon: <?php echo $_SESSION[emailcontact]; ?>  <Br />
Bent u een accounting bedrijf? <?php echo $_SESSION[accounting]; ?>  <Br />
Door u gekozen abonnement: <?php echo $_SESSION[abonnement]; ?>  <Br />
Gewenste gebruikersnaam: <?php echo $_SESSION[gebruikersnaam]; ?>  <Br />
Boekhoudprogramma: <?php echo $_SESSION[boekhoudprogramma]; ?>  <Br />
Twinfield abonnement? <?php echo $_SESSION[twinfield]; ?>  <Br /><br />
Betalingsmethode: <?php echo $_SESSION[betalingsmethode]; ?>  <Br />
E-mailadres factuur: <?php echo $_SESSION[emailfactuur]; ?>  <Br />
Bank: <?php echo $_SESSION[bank]; ?>  <Br />
Tenaamstelling: <?php echo $_SESSION[tenaamstelling]; ?>  <Br />
Rekeningnummer: <?php echo $_SESSION[rekeningnummer]; ?>  <Br />
Toestemming tot afschrijving: <?php echo $_SESSION[afschrijving]; ?>  <Br />
Akkoord met de voorwaarden? <?php echo $_SESSION[voorwaarden]; ?>  <Br />
Bent u gemachtigd? <?php echo $_SESSION[gemachtigd]; ?>  <Br /><Br />



Verstuurd op <?php echo $datum; ?>  via het ip <?php echo $ip; ?> <Br /><Br /> 
Onze Algemene Voorwaarden: <A style=\"color:#2873ba\" href=\"https://www.***.nl/wp-content/uploads/general/TC/***-AV-v1-1-NL.pdf\">https://www.***.nl/wp-content/uploads/general/TC/***-AV-v1-1-NL.pdf</a><Br />
Onze Service level agreement: <A style=\"color:#2873ba\" href=\"https://www.***.nl/wp-content/uploads/general/TC/***-SLA-v1-2-NL.pdf\">https://www.***.nl/wp-content/uploads/general/TC/***-SLA-v1-2-NL.pdf</a><Br />
Dat u deze mail ontvangt betekend dat u akkoord ging<br />
met het bovenstaande. Opzegging is kosteloos mogelijk binnen 30 dagen.<Br /><Br />
Met vriendelijke groet,<Br />
*** N.V.<Br />
E-mail: <a href=\"mailto:info@***.nl\" style=\"color:#2873ba\"> info@***.nl</a><Br />







</p><Br /><Br />

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style=\"background-color:#ababab;\" >
                        <img src=\"http://www.***.nl/email/pic.png\" style=\"margin-top:2px\">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style=\"padding: 10px; background-color:#2873ba;\" >
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style=\"padding: 10px;\" >
                        <br /><Br /><Br />
                    </td>
                </tr>


            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>



";
    $inhoud_mail2 .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";









    $_POST['onderwerp2'] = str_replace("\n", "", $_POST['onderwerp2']); // Verwijder \n 
    $_POST['onderwerp2'] = str_replace("\r", "", $_POST['onderwerp2']); // Verwijder \r 
    $_POST['onderwerp2'] = str_replace("\"", "\\\"", str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $_POST['onderwerp2'])); // Slashes van quotes 

    mail($mail_ontv2, $_POST['onderwerp2'], $inhoud_mail2, $headers2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$inhoud_mail2 .= "   
<html>
<body leftmargin=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" topmargin=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" offset=\"0\">
<table width=\"100%\" bgcolor=\"#e7e7e7\" cellpadding=\"10\" cellspacing=\"0\" background=\"http://www.***.nl/email/bc.jpg\">
    <tr valign=\"top\" align=\"center\">
        <td>
            <table width=\"550\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src=\"http://www.***.nl/email/email-header.png\" alt=\"Header **** Email\" /><br /><br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style=\"margin: 25px; padding:15px\" bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">
                        <h2 style=\"color:#545454; font-weight:600; font-size: 20px; letter-spacing:-1px; font-family:Verdana, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;\">Aanmelding ***!</h2>
                        <p style=\"color:#3d3d3d;font-family:Verdana, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; line-height: 20px; font-size: 14px;\">
                            U heeft zich zojuist succesvol aangemeld bij ***.<br /><br /><Br />     
                            <b>Uw gegevens:</b><br /><Br />
                            Bedrijfsnaam: $_SESSION[bedrijfsnaam]  <Br /> 
                            Adres: $_SESSION[straat]  $_SESSION[huisnummer] <Br /> 
                            Postcode: $_SESSION[postcode]  <Br />
                            Plaats: $_SESSION[plaats]  <Br /> 
                            Telefoonnummer: $_SESSION[telefoonnummer]  <Br />
                            E-mail adres: $_SESSION[email]  <Br />
                            KvK-nummer: $_SESSION[kvk]  <Br />
                            BTW-nummer: $_SESSION[btw]  <Br />
                            Rechtsvorm: $_SESSION[rechtsvorm]  <Br /><Br />
                            Contactpersoon: $_SESSION[contactpersoon]  <Br />
                            Geslacht: $_SESSION[geslachtcontactpersoon]  <Br />
                            Tel. nr. contactpersoon: $_SESSION[telefoonnummercontact]  <Br />
                            E-mail adres contactpersoon: $_SESSION[emailcontact]  <Br />
                            Bent u een accounting bedrijf? $_SESSION[accounting]  <Br />
                            Door u gekozen abonnement: $_SESSION[abonnement]  <Br />
                            Gewenste gebruikersnaam: $_SESSION[gebruikersnaam]  <Br />
                            Boekhoudprogramma: $_SESSION[boekhoudprogramma]  <Br />
                            Twinfield abonnement? $_SESSION[twinfield]  <Br /><br />
                            Betalingsmethode: $_SESSION[betalingsmethode]  <Br />
                            E-mailadres factuur: $_SESSION[emailfactuur]  <Br />
                            Bank: $_SESSION[bank]  <Br />
                            Tenaamstelling: $_SESSION[tenaamstelling]  <Br />
                            Rekeningnummer: $_SESSION[rekeningnummer]  <Br />
                            Toestemming tot afschrijving: $_SESSION[afschrijving]  <Br />
                            Akkoord met de voorwaarden? $_SESSION[voorwaarden]  <Br />
                            Bent u gemachtigd? $_SESSION[gemachtigd]  <Br /><Br />
                            Verstuurd op $datum  via het ip $ip <Br /><Br /> 
                            Onze Algemene Voorwaarden: <A style=\"color:#2873ba\" href=\"https://www.***.nl/wp-content/uploads/general/TC/***-AV-v1-1-NL.pdf\">https://www.***.nl/wp-content/uploads/general/TC/***-AV-v1-1-NL.pdf</a><Br />
                            Onze Service level agreement: <A style=\"color:#2873ba\" href=\"https://www.***.nl/wp-content/uploads/general/TC/***-SLA-v1-2-NL.pdf\">https://www.***.nl/wp-content/uploads/general/TC/***-SLA-v1-2-NL.pdf</a><Br />
                            Dat u deze mail ontvangt betekend dat u akkoord ging<br />
                            met het bovenstaande. Opzegging is kosteloos mogelijk binnen 30 dagen.<Br /><Br />
                            Met vriendelijke groet,<Br />
                            *** N.V.<Br />
                            E-mail: <a href=\"mailto:info@***.nl\" style=\"color:#2873ba\"> info@***.nl</a><Br />
                        </p><Br /><Br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style=\"background-color:#ababab;\" >
                        <img src=\"http://www.***.nl/email/pic.png\" style=\"margin-top:2px\">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style=\"padding: 10px; background-color:#2873ba;\" >
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style=\"padding: 10px;\" >
                        <br /><Br /><Br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>";
```

You nned to replace just the $inhoud_mail2 data with this one . . Your problem will be solved . . Cheers ! !

Comment: Gonna test it right now, you removed all the php opening en closing tags and the echoes right?